# Fitting image into div

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to fit an image into a div, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```css
#header {
border: 10px solid blue;
width: 50%;
height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'header'>
<img src = "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set your `img` width to 100% and it will scale to the width of the `#header` container.

```css
#header {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
}
img {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id = 'header'>
  <img src = "https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look.Change your css into this way. Set `img` tag in your css.Working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gbpywc93/)

CSS:

```
 #header img{
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  }
```

You can also set `img{width:100%}` .Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `background-size: cover` like this:

**CSS**

```
#header {
  border: 10px solid blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20%;
  background: url(https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg);
  background-size: cover
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header"></div>
```